# Unable to install Napalm-fortios module in my pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, automation, napalm

I'm learning network automation using python. I'm unable to install Napalm-fortios module in my pycharm because of the error as below.

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DUKE\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.

Collecting napalm-fortios
  Using cached napalm-fortios-0.4.1.tar.gz (7.0 kB)

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DUKE\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\napalm-fortios\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\napalm-fortios\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\napalm-fortios\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\napalm-fortios\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\napalm-fortios\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Adding import statements, code snippets used and the steps/commands which you had tried executing to install the module will make it easier for others to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update PIP using below command,

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Command to install napalm-fortios package,

```
pip install napalm-fortios
```

Comment: I am using windows 10 here.. I am able to install in ubuntu... not in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution steps;

The Python "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'" occurs when `pip` is not installed in our Python environment. To solve the error, install the module by running the `python -m ensurepip --upgrade` command on Linux or MacOS or `py -m ensurepip --upgrade` on Windows.

Open your terminal and run the following command to install pip.

**On Linux or MacOS**

> `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

**using python 3**

> `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`

**On Windows**

> `py -m ensurepip --upgrade`

The `ensurepip` package enables us to bootstrap the `pip` installer into an existing Python installation or virtual environment.

If the PATH for `pip` is not set up on your machine, replace pip with `python3 -m pip`:

make sure to use your version of Python, e.g. 3.10

> `python3 -m pip install requests`

Alternatively, you can use the [official get-pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) script to install pip.

Download the script from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py by clicking on the link, right-clicking and selecting "Save as" in your browser.

Open your terminal in the location where the `get-pip.py` file is downloaded and run the following command.

**On Linux or MacOS**

> `python get-pip.py`

**using python 3**

> `python3 get-pip.py`

**On Windows**

> `py get-pip.py`

The `get-pip.py` script uses bootstrapping logic to install `pip`.

If none of the suggestions helped, try to install `pip` with a command that's specific to your operating system.

**On Debian / Ubuntu**

> `sudo apt update`
>
> `sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip`

**On MacOS**

> `brew install python`

**On Fedora / CentOS**

> `sudo dnf install python3-pip python3-wheel`

Try upgrading `pip` by running:

**on MacOS or Linux**

> `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

**for Python 3**

> `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

**on Windows**

> `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

If the error persists, get your Python version and make sure you are installing the package using the correct Python version.

> `python --version`

For example, my Python version is `3.10.4`, so I would install the requests package with `pip3.10 install requests`.

> `pip3.10 install requests`

if you get permissions error

`sudo pip3.10 install requests`

Notice that the version number corresponds to the version of Python I'm using.

If that didn't help and you're using a virtual environment, try recreating it.

***deactivate***

> `deactivate`

***remove the old virtual environment folder***

> `rm -rf venv`

***initialize a new virtual environment***

> `python3 -m venv venv`

***activate on Unix or MacOS***

> `source venv/bin/activate`

***activate on Windows (cmd.exe)***

> `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

***activate on Windows (PowerShell)***

> `venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

***install the modules in your requirements.txt file***

> `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Your virtual environment will use the version of Python that was used to create it.

This should work if your previous virtual environment didn't have `pip` installed for some reason.

> If none of the suggestions helped on a Windows machine, try installing
> `pip` from the directory where the `pip.exe` file is located.

First locate Python by running the following command using `cmd`:

***for Windows***

> `where python`

***or a specific version if you have multiple installed***

> `where python3`

Now open the `Scripts` folder and make sure it contains the `pip.exe` file.

Open your command prompt in the `Scripts` directory right next to the `pip.exe` file and run the following command.

> `pip install pip`
>
> `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

*If the error persists, I would suggest watching a quick video on how to set Python and pip in your PATH environment variable.*

Ref. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-pip